# Input was not Found in Haystack ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

i am getting this error

```
 Array ( [name] => Array ( [notInArray] => The input was not found in the haystack ) [account] => Array ( [notInArray] => The input was not found in the haystack ) )
```

Where as i have done something like this in my Form

```
   $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'name' => 'name',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Account Name:',
            'disable_inarray_validator' => true,
            'value_options' => array(
                '0' => 'Select',
            ),

        ),
    ));
```

All this **'disable_inarray_validator' => true,** do is that it disables the message. I still cant validate my Form. I have checked rest of my form after disabling the **Select Feilds** and it is validating fine.

Comment: Can you provide posted data?

Comment: I cant Provide Posted Data Atm which is TOO long. but I can tell you what my Name Looks like Array(name=>array('1'=>'23','2'=>'24','3'=>'25'.....)) some thing like this